# After changing the OS Will signed key will be same or it will change

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and I generated one signed key for application.
Now I want to change my PC OS. After changing the  OS will same signed key work for generating signed application ?

Comment: no it will not for more info http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: This isn't a programming related question. This would probably be better received on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to key store. Yes, the key store file will work regardless of the OS.